# Command to see 'R' path that RStudio is using

Tags: r, linux, path, exec

## Original Question

This seems easy and has likely been asked before, but I could not find it via a search.

---

I have a few flavors of `R` installed.  I simply want to know, when I run RStudio, which flavor of `R` is it pointing to.  So, I need a command -- within RStudio itself, ideally -- that can tell me the underlying `R` executable that is being used for this RStudio window that I am currently working with.

---

To be clear, I do not need / want to know the **version** of R that I'm using (e.g., `R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- 'Fire Safety'`).  Instead, I want to know the actual path that RStudio is using to get to R -- looking at it from within RStudio -- so that I know "for reals" which version it's using.  (E.g., `/usr/local/bin/R`.)

---

## Edit & Answer

There are a lot of great discussions here, and some are OS-specific.  I have a Mac.  In my case, I found that:

```
> system("type R")
R is /usr/local/bin/R

> R.home()
[1] "/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources"

> file.path(R.home("bin"), "R")
[1] "/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/bin/R"
```

As those of you familiar can see, I am using [`brew`](http://brew.sh/).  If I look for `/usr/local/bin/R` outside of R, I see:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/R
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mike  admin  25 Nov 14 17:31 /usr/local/bin/R -> ../Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/bin/R
```

which eventually resolves (2 symbolic links) to:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/bin/R
```

as the final destination.

So on my system (Mac OS X), ***`file.path(R.home("bin"), "R")` was the most accurate***.

Comment: try `Sys.getenv('R_HOME')` or `R.home()` (faster)

Comment: you could also go to Tools and Global Options, it will be the first line in General

Comment: For example in R/RStudio on Linux, `system("type R")`. On my Linux, it says `R is /usr/bin/R`.

Comment: @JorisMeys  That's not the OP's question.

Comment: Side note: On my Linux, `file.path(R.home("bin"), "R")` doesn't return the path to the executable currently used by RStudio. This command `system("type R | xargs readlink")` does.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**(Edited to reflect fact that this is apparently a Windows-specific solution.)**

Here on Windows, I'd use the following, for reasons [discussed here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-May/064147.html) by Henrik Bengtsson near the start of a long thread on the subject.

```
file.path(R.home("bin"), "R")
```

This is better than using `file.path(R.home(), "bin", "R")` in several settings alluded to in the "Value" section of this snippet from `help(R.home)`:

> Details:
>
> The R home directory is the top-level directory of the R
>    installation being run.
>
> [...]
>
> Value:
>
> A character string giving the R home directory or path to a
>    particular component. Normally the components are all subdirectories
>    of the R home directory, but this may not be the case in a Unix-like
>    installation.  [...] The return value for "modules" and on Windows
>    "bin" is to a sub-architecture-specific location.

Comment: But it doesn't give the current path used. On my machine, it gives `/usr/lib/R/bin/R`, which is incorrect. My default R binary is located in `/usr/bin/R`. If I change it for `/usr/bin/R.old`, RStudio won't run.

Comment: @Pascal Can you be more specific? Do you mean that it doesn't  point to `Rcmd.exe` or `Rgui.exe` or `Rterm.exe`, if those are what were used? If so I agree, but (guessing here) think the OP is just wanting the path along which the version of R that RStudio's using is found. If you're saying that it gives that path incorrectly, though, I'll have to disagree (until you show me an example).

Comment: I just say that my RStudio uses `/usr/bin/R`, while `file.path(R.home("bin"), "R")` points to `/usr/lib/R/bin/R`.

Comment: @Pascal It's been a long time since I've used R on *NIX, but is there any chance that `/usr/bin/R` is a script that eventually launches the executable at `/usr/lib/R/bin/R`? (I'd check myself, but don't have access a non-Windows machine right now.)

Comment: Just checked on my Linux. First, `/usr/bin/R` is not a link to `/usr/lib/R/bin/R` (checked with `file /usr/bin/R`). Then, using `diff -y <(xxd /usr/bin/R) <(xxd /usr/lib/R/bin/R) | colordiff` shows no difference between two binaries.

Comment: @Pascal Interesting. Thanks for checking. (FWIW, I wasn't expecting it to be a link, but do recall that long ago (5+ years) typing R from the *NIX command line found a shell script `R.sh`, in `/usr/local/bin`, and that script would then invoke the R binary, found elsewhere. Doing `whereis R` (back then) might only find the shell script and not the actual compiled executable.)

Comment: On my Linux, I get `R: /usr/bin/R /usr/lib/R /usr/share/man/man1/R.1` for `whereis R`.

Comment: @Pascal Well, if `/usr/bin/R` not a shell script and if that's what Rstudio's actually launching, I'm pretty much at a loss as to what's going on. It certainly doesn't seem to fit with the documented behavior of `?R.home` (see the `"Details"` section), nor with the general tenor of Simon Urbanek's comments in the thread linked in my answer. Oh well, I'm off for the evening.

Comment: Actually, you should just try R.home(). That's the top-level directory from which R is run. On Linux, the "bin" folder of the R installation doesn't need to be in the same location as the actual R installation. That's why I wonder why @JoshO'Brien uses R.home("bin"). This doesn't seem the information OP is after.

Comment: @Pascal: what does `Sys.getenv('R_HOME')` and `R.home()` return for you (I'm on Windows so can't test for Linux)

Comment: @etienne  Both gives `/usr/lib/R`.

Comment: @Pascal I misunderstood the question apparently, my bad. But on a Linux  system you still shouldn't use 'bin' but 'modules'. 'bin' is -to my understanding- Windows specific. What do you get from `file.path(R.home("modules"), "R")`

Comment: @JorisMeys  On a lot of Linux distributions, binaries are located in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`. On Windows, it is `Program Files`.

Comment: @Pascal I quote from the help file of `?R.home`: The value for "modules" and on Windows "bin" is a sub-architecture-specific location.  I'm talking about the settings for `R.home()`, not the directory structure of the OS. So what do you get?

Comment: @JorisMeys Yes, sorry. Well, I get `"/usr/lib/R/bin/R"`, which is correct. But as I said previously, this executable is not used by my RStudio.

Comment: @Pascal What do you get when you directly launch `/usr/lib/R` (outside of RStudio) and do `R.home()` from the launched session?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I get nothing, as `/usr/lib/R` is a directory.

Comment: @Pascal -- My bad, I meant what do you get when you launch `usr/bin/R`?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien  It gives `/usr/lib/R`. So, in summary, your answer applied to Windows, while OP's edit applies to OSX. But it doesn't apply to Linux, or at least to my installation. If I create a symbolic link in `ln -s /usr/bin/R ~/bin/R`, then run `~/bin/R`, I get for `system("type R")` `R is /home/xxx/bin/R`, which is incorrect (it shows the symbolic link). `R.home()` still gives `"/usr/lib/R"`. Finally, this command is the correct approach: `system("type R | xargs readlink")`, which gives `/usr/bin/R`.

Comment: @Pascal Or perhaps your RStudio actually does use `/usr/lib/R/bin/R`, and is trying to tell you so? (Not trying to be argumentative -- just wondering how you know that RStudio is using `/usr/lib/R` when it tells you otherwise. `system("type R")` after all tells you about the R that's first on your shell's search path, not necessarily the one you're currently running.)

Comment: This is a good answer. Another for the binary executable path, from interactive mode, is: `commandArgs()[1]`

Comment: Why is the path truncated ?