# Running R Script within Stata - "permission denied"

Tags: r, shell, stata

I am working on a project where I need to run an R script within Stata. I have the following code written:

```
shell "/Users/alexanderrbilly/Desktop/Neel/cleaner.R" CMD BATCH "cleaner.R"
```

Despite even changing the command directory before this (which shouldn't matter), I keep getting the same error:

```
/bin/bash: /Users/alexanderrbilly/Desktop/Neel/cleaner.R: Permission denied
```

Let me know if I'm doing something erroneous or how I may get around this issue.

Comment: You are not calling an R executable only the script which is only a text file. Consider the automated Rscript: `/path/to/Rscript /path/to/cleaner.R`

Answer (score 1):

Your command line is not correct.

Your string `"/Users/alexanderrbilly/Desktop/Neel/cleaner.R"` should be a path to your R executable.

If you are on Windows. Say a file `K:\tmp\random.R` contains the code `write.csv(rnorm(10), "a.csv")`.
Then, you can write in Stata:

```
cd K:\tmp
shell C:\APPLI\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x64\R.exe CMD BATCH random.R
```

Of course, change the path to your R executable to fit your installation.

If you are on Linux, the error probably comes from the fact that `cleaner.R` does not have the [execute permission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions). You may also have a look at [What's the best way to use R scripts on the command line (terminal)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750786/whats-the-best-way-to-use-r-scripts-on-the-command-line-terminal)

Comment: Cool! I used `file.path(R.home("bin"), "R")` to identify the R executable path and it seems to be working right now (for those unsure of how to extract the path). 

I used information from this page: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798115/command-to-see-r-path-that-rstudio-is-using)

Comment: So you are on macOS. The problem is not much different, but you have to find the path, if R is not already in the PATH environment variable: in a Terminal, does the command "R" launch something? You may also start the R application and type `Sys.getenv("PATH")` to find out where the executable may be.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you changed your comment. It's another way to find.

Comment: @JuliusBilly You may also be interested by the package rsource from ssc. For more information, type `ssc describe rsource` in Stata. To install, type `ssc install rsource`.