# Opening R script on Mac through Stata

Tags: r, shell, stata

I want to *run* an R script through stata. I can successfully *open* the script this way:

`shell open -a RStudio "PATHWAY/filename.R"`

And in terminal, I can successfully *run* the script through the command:

`Rscript "PATHWAY/filename.R"`

I thought that `shell` allowed me to pass Stata terminal commands. However, `shell Rscript "PATHWAY/filename.R"` returns the error `/bin/bash: Rscript: command not found`.

I see that [others](https://statlore.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/how-to-call-r-from-stata/comment-page-1/#comment-192) execute R scripts via something like

`shell "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH test.R`

However, I am unsure about the equivalent R command pathway on my Mac. (Or why I need a pathway at all, since I can execute the file in terminal w/ the mere command Rscript, and can open the file w/ shell in stata, without a pathway.) Following [notes here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798115/command-to-see-r-path-that-rstudio-is-using), I find that `file.path(R.home("bin"), "R")`
returns `"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R"`, but adding this path way to the command (`shell /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R/R.exe "PATHWAY/filename.R"`) doesn't help at all.

Additionally, I am aware of the [Rsource package](https://econpapers.repec.org/software/bocbocode/s456847.htm), but I think this is more capability than I need. I don't want to run the R code within Stata, or import R objects into Stata after running. I merely want Stata to tell terminal "Run this particular R script," and then wait for the run to complete before continuing on with the Stata code. So I *think* shell is the right avenue, if I can get it to work.

Would appreciate mac-specific advice! Cross-posted on [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1415988-running-r-script-through-terminal-via-shell-from-stata).

Leah

Comment: It looks like the path `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R/R.exe` is calling the R executable, not Rscript. You can likely execute your R code from within Stata using `shell "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R/R" CMD BATCH "PATHWAY/filename.R"`. Alternatively, you can search the path of the R executable given by RStudio to find the Rscript executable and try calling that directly in place of `Rscript "PATHWAY/filename.R"`. Also, consider looking at environment variables to see that `$PATH` (or OS X equivalent) is pointing to the Rscript executable.

Comment: Thank you! That ALMOST works --- if I get rid of the last slash R, it does work. So this runs: `shell "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R" CMD BATCH "PATHWAY/filename.R"`.  Thanks a lot! Additionally, this vanilla command runs: `shell /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R --vanilla <PATHWAY/filename.R`. (That was given to me on the cross-listed Stata listserve link I gave above.) I'm not entirely sure about the difference between these two commands, vanilla vs. CMD BATCH. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Oops, yeah forgot to remove that extra `/R`. But honestly I can't speak to the difference between the two methods - this is largely new territory for me. I've used `Rscript` and `R CMD BATCH` under Windows and Linux, but have never had issues and never tried via `Shell` in Stata. You might find Appendix B from the R-intro docs to be worth reading: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Comment: Wow, thank you! Yes, Appendix B is very helpful, indeed. Thanks so much for pointing it out!