# How do you run an R script from Windows command line with only RStudio installed?

Tags: r, command-line, rstudio, rscript

I have a machine that only has RStudio installed.  It does NOT have Rscript.exe which is how I normally run R code from the Windows command line.

How do I run R code from the command line on a Windows machine that only has RStudio installed?  They can NOT install the normal R runtime so I need something that comes with RStudio.

Thanks!

Comment: You, can't.  Rscript.exe is R, Rstudio is just an IDE for R.

Comment: If you don't have admin privilege, download the portable version of R from the official page and extract to your own folder and run R from there

Comment: But RStudio needs the normal R runtime in order to actually process your R commands. How do you have RStudio installed and working without R?

Comment: See: [Command to see 'R' path that RStudio is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798115/command-to-see-r-path-that-rstudio-is-using)

Answer (score 0):

Rscript is a scripting front-end, which calls for and uses R. You cannot make successful calls to R without having R. If you just have Rstudio you will not be able to run R since it is assumed that you install R.

Use the portable version of R if you do not have admin privileges.